# Probability of an edge to be crossing

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

This is a doubt I had while studying *The Probabilistic Method* by Alon and Spencer. In the chapter on the linearity of expectations, a theorem is as follows:

**Theorem:** If $G$ is a graph on $2n$ vertices and $e$ edges then it has a bipartite subgraph with at least $\frac{en}{2n-1}$ edges, and if $G$ had $2n+1$ vertices then it has a bipartite subgraph with at least $\frac{e(n+1)}{2n+1}$ edges.

In the proof, a set $T$ is chosen uniformly among all $n$ element subsets of $V(G)$. Then it is mentioned that any edge $xy$ has an $\frac{n}{2n-1}$ probability of being crossing between $T$ and $V(G)\backslash T$.  ($\frac{n+1}{2n+1}$ in the $2n+1$ case).  I'm trying to reason this out.

What I think is that WLOG we can fix $x \in T$. Now $P[y \in V(G) \backslash T] =\frac{n}{2n-1} $ as there are $n$ vertices outside of $T$ and $y$ can be any of them, out of the remaining $2n-1$ vertices. But I am confused because $x$ need not have an edge with all $2n-1$ of these vertices, so shouldn't the probability be $\frac{|N(x) \cap (V(G) \backslash T)|}{|N(x)| }$ ? Where am I going wrong? [here $N(x)$ is the set of neighbours of $x$]

Comment: Of course $x$ doesn't need to have an edge with all $2n-1$ other vertices... but $x$ *does* have an edge with $y$... wherever $y$ happened to be.

Comment: We know ahead of time that $xy$ is an edge.  We randomly split the vertices into two equally sized sets.  $x$ will happen to go to one of the two sets, it matters not which.  Now... $y$ will go into one of the two sets as well and will end up having been put into the other set as $x$ with probability $\frac{n}{2n-1}$.  Only after having decided what set $x$ went into and $y$ went into do we concern ourselves again with the fact that there is the edge between them.  The random process at play here didn't care that they had an edge.  The same would have been true of $x$ and some other $z$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks!